# Why did Samba shares stop working out of nowhere?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, network-shares, samba

I'm hosting a home server using Ubuntu 22.04. I've been using Samba to share a drive with my Windows 10 system for a couple days now, today out of nowhere I can no longer access the drive through Samba.

It started after I started using Hamachi on the Windows system but I don't think it’s related as I've done it before. I restarted Samba by using `sudo service smbd restart` and I made sure the drive was still mounted both by using `realpath` and the GUI. And I tried restarting both systems.

No changes have been made to the `smb.conf` or the UFW so I think it’s the Windows system, but I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: Are you receiving any errors on the Windows? Did you check the event log on the Windows for any related errors? Did you try to access yours Samba shares from another system, for example, Android?

Comment: Did you check the system log _on the server_?

Comment: Try to temporarily disable all firewalls in-between the two computers.

Comment: Were the shares configured for SMBv1 instead of SMBv2 and above only? On Windows, _SMB Direct_ should be enabled and _SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support_ disabled in `OptionalFeatures`, with `SMB2` set as the minimum in the Samba server config _(this does require a user with a passphrase for accessing the shares on Windows)_

Answer (score 0):

Two options, one for the client and one for the server. Choose the one (not both) that works best for you:

1. Add your Samba credentials to the Windows Credential Manager. This requires a fix on every client
2. Change `map to guest = bad user` in your Samba configuration to `map to guest = never`. This requires a fix on every server and is the (more) correct option

References

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/guest-access-in-smb2-is-disabled-by-default#symptoms
- https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/storage-at-microsoft/smb-signing-and-guest-authentication/ba-p/3846679
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/guest-access-in-smb2-is-disabled-by-default
- https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Standalone_Server

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure its the VPN. It is likely not routing local traffic and/or also firewalls traffic.  I would disable the VPN first, and then see if the SAMBA share works.  Once we've confirmed that's where the issue is we can look at adjusting the iptables or firewall to properly route traffic on the LAN.

Another test would be to drop to command prompt and see if you can ping the server.  If the server doesn't responding with VPN on then almost certainly VPN is the cause.